# Unique binary search trees

Tags: python, tree

I have written some code that prints out all unique pre-ordered binary search trees containing numbers `1` to `n`.

It is not an especially efficient solution and has a time complexity (I believe) of O(n!) but hopefully it is fairly easy to understand.

As I am using `sets` the output is not sorted.

```
"""Module constructs and prints unique BST."""
import itertools
class Node():
    """Builds a BST"""
    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
    def add_node(self, value):
        """Adds new elemenet to binary search tree."""
        if self.value:
            if value > self.value:
                if not self.right:
                    self.right = Node(value)
                else:
                    self.right.add_node(value)
            else:
                if not self.left:
                    self.left = Node(value)
                else:
                    self.left.add_node(value)
    def print_tree(self):
        """Return the BST as a string"""
        string_tree = ""
        if self.value:
            string_tree += (str(self.value) + " ")
            if self.left:
                string_tree += self.left.print_tree()
            if self.right:
                string_tree += self.right.print_tree()
        return string_tree

def build_BST(permutation):
    """Builds a BST from a list of numbers"""
    if permutation:
        tree = Node(permutation[0])
        for i in range(1, len(permutation)):
            tree.add_node(permutation[i])
        string_tree = tree.print_tree()
        return string_tree
    return False

def build_trees(size_tree):
    """Build BST containing numbers in range 1 to n"""
    if not isinstance(size_tree, int):
        print("Please enter an integer")
        return
    if size_tree <= 0:
        print("Function only prints trees with numbers >= 1")
        return
    permutations = list(itertools.permutations([i for i in range(1, size_tree + 1)],
                                               size_tree))
    set_solutions = set()
    for permutation in permutations:
        string_tree = build_BST(permutation)
        set_solutions.add(string_tree)
    for solution in set_solutions:
        print(solution)
    print(f"==========\n{len(set_solutions)} solutions.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    build_trees(4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some suggestions:

- You can use [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) or [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to pass the size on the command line. The latter can check the type and range for you, and print an appropriate error message and usage string. You can [specify a validator function in the `type` argument to check for non-trivial values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14117511/96588).
- `print_tree` does not print the tree, it returns a string representation of it. That is the job of `__str__`, a special internal method you can override to define the string representation of a class.
- "node" in `add_node` is redundant.
- Running this code through `black` will improve the formatting slightly. `flake8` and `mypy` (with a strict configuration) can help make the code more idiomatic.

Comment: I can see how ```argparse``` can throw a non ```int``` error. But I can't work out how to throw a neat out of range error (the ```choices``` argument is very ugly)